# Centos 7.0 update command not working

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, updates

I have just installed CentOS 7 on my PC. After install completed I tried to update CentOS using the `yum update` command:

```
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for base
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/packages/dhclient-4.2.5-36.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for dhclient-4.2.5-36.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/320): dhclient-4.2.5-36.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm           | 278 kB   00:03     
(2/320): dhcp-common-4.2.5-36.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm        | 171 kB   00:04     
(3/320): dmraid-events-1.0.0.rc16-25.el7.x86_64.rpm        |  21 kB   00:01     
(4/320): dmraid-1.0.0.rc16-25.el7.x86_64.rpm               | 150 kB   00:02     
(5/320): dhcp-libs-4.2.5-36.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm          | 127 kB   00:02     
Traceback (most recent call last):              ] 508 kB/s | 5.3 MB   09:41 ETA 
  File "/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down", line 61, in main
    fo = PyCurlFileObject(opts.url, opts.filename, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1258, in __init__
    self._do_open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1589, in _do_open
    self._do_grab()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1723, in _do_grab
    self._do_perform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1517, in _do_perform
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It shows this error:

```
No Presto metadata available for base
```

Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is due to a bug in the urlgrabber python script:
To mitigate this issue you can edit the line 1510 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py

Then replace the line number 1510 :

```
elif errcode in (42, 55, 56):
```

with this:

```
elif errcode == 42:
```

I recently faced this issue and found this solution from CentOS forums where you can read more about the issue:  https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47372&start=10